# QT: Arbitrarily complex data structures with QVariant

Tags: c++, qt

Quoting the QT Docs:

> You can even store QList and QMap values in
>   a variant, so you can easily construct arbitrarily complex data 
>   structures of arbitrary types. This is very powerful and versatile, 
>   but may prove less memory and speed efficient than storing specific 
>   types in standard data structures.

Does anyone know of, or have, an example of doing exactly this?

I'm a long time C++ programmer, but a QT Nube, and the copy of write semantics are giving me fits. Maps and Lists of QVariants data structures seems immutable. Every time I try to modify a tree of values, I just end up modifying a copy.

---

Got some feedback from my first post that I should add an example. Here goes:

```
// Input Data:
//
// { "f1"   : "field-1",
//   "list" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
//

// Convert the data, commented above, into a QVariantMap with two 
// values:
//  "f1"   - a string
//  "list" - a QVariantList of integers
QVariant vData = ConvertJsonDocument(document);

// Dump
qWarning( VariantToString(vData).toLocal8Bit() );

// Convert vData to QVariantMap
QVariantMap vMap = vData.value<QVariantMap>();
// Get the list of integers as a QVariantList
QVariantList vList = vMap["list"].value<QVariantList>();
// Change the 0 to a 5
vList[0] = 5;

// Dump
qWarning( VariantToString(vData).toLocal8Bit() );
```

Output from above:

```
{ "f1" : "field-1", "list" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ "f1" : "field-1", "list" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```

DESIRED output from above:

```
{ "f1" : "field-1", "list" : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ "f1" : "field-1", "list" : [ 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```

I get that I am modifying copies, but for the life of my I can't figure out how NOT to. How do I edit the original source data? (The data in the tree rooted at vData.)

Comment: i dont really understand the question. The docs just say that you can get basically any structure with a `QVariant`, so bascially anything can be an example

Comment: I think you're more likely to get help with this if you can provide a specific example showing what you're trying to accomplish as well as the problems you encountered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll come up with a small example and update the post.

Comment: Any class can be passed as a QVariant, if it meets certain restrictions and is registered with the QMetaType system. Try reading the description of [QMetaType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you make the desired alterations, you need to go back through the tree and update your variables with the new data.

```
// Convert vData to QVariantMap
QVariantMap vMap = vData.value<QVariantMap>();
// Get the list of integers as a QVariantList
QVariantList vList = vMap["list"].value<QVariantList>();
// Change the 0 to a 5
vList[0] = 5;

// Change the map using insert, which replaces the value
vMap.insert("list", vList);
// Rebuild the QVariant from the QMap
vData = QVariant::fromValue(vMap);
// Dump
qWarning( VariantToString(vData).toLocal8Bit() );
```

You can convert the data back from the QVariant and update the source document from there.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I'm coming at this from NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary in the Foundation classes, and they just work differently. I guess the rule is that anything you pull out of a tree is copied out of the tree, so if you modify the copy you have to put it back.